# Converting a product of a sum to a sum of product (not boolean algebra)

Tags: functions, summation

I have been wondering about this for quite some time but did not find any simplified solution.
Is there a way to convert the following:
$$\prod_{i=1}^k \sum_{j=1}^n x_{j,i} $$
where $x_j$ is just some real value, to some other formula in which we sum the products?

I hope this was clear enough, if not I will try my best to add more info.

---

**Edit:** There are k series of numbers ($x_j$ are series of n numbers) and $x_{j,i}$ is the i'th number is the j'th series.

Answer (score 0):

What you have there, I assume starting indices to be $1$, can be simplified and then expressed by the binomial theorem:
$$\prod_{i=1}^k \sum_{j=1}^n x_j = \left( \sum_{j=1}^n x_j \right)^k = \sum_{i=0}^k \binom ki x_1^i \left( \sum_{j=2}^n x_j \right)^{k-i}$$
Proceed inductively.

Comment: yes sorry for not mentioning about the indices, you are correct they both start at 1. Is the first part of the equation the binomial theorem? ( $\prod_{i=1}^k \sum_{j=1}^n x_j = \left( \sum_{j=1}^n x_j \right)^k$ ). If so this could really help.

Comment: No, the first is just dropping the product of $k$-times the same and instead writing $\text{(the same)}^k$. The second step is the binomial theorem $$(a+b)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom nk a^k b^{n-k}$$
Applied to $a=x_1$ and $b = \sum_{j=2}^n x_j$

Comment: oh sorry my bad! there is an index missing it was supposed to be: $(x_j)_i$. $x_j$ are series of numbers and we are looking at the i'th index in the sequence. I will update my question.